# How to use this CCITT-CRC16 function?

Tags: c

Over [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/implementing-the-ccitt-cyclical-redundan/199904926), there is an implementation of CCITT-CRC16. For those avoiding links, it's written out in C like so:

```
unsigned short crc16(data_p, length)
char *data_p;
unsigned short length;
{
       unsigned char i;
       unsigned int data;
       unsigned int crc;

       crc = 0xffff;

       if (length == 0)
              return (~crc);

       do {
              for (i = 0 data = (unsigned int)0xff & *data_p++;
                  i < 8;
                  i++, data >>= 1) {
                    if ((crc & 0x0001) ^ (data & 0x0001))
                           crc = (crc >> 1) ^ POLY;
                    else
                           crc >>= 1;
              }
       } while (--length);

       crc = ~crc;

       data = crc;
       crc = (crc << 8) | (data >> 8 & 0xFF);

       return (crc);
}
```

But I am confused as to how it will apply to my case. I am translating from a private/unknown language, which has a built in CCITT CRC16. It has a CRC class function like so:

> CRCname.put(int byte):
>
> byte is an integer value used to update the current CRC. Only the
>   lowest 8 bits of the parameter are used.

I need two fields in CCITT-CRC16 implementation that I found, `data_p` and `length`, so my question is... what is meant by the integer value used to update the crc? Inside the code I'm translating, the program executes `crc.put(someChar)` quite a lot, then changing `someChar` before calling `crc.put(someChar)` again, and it does it multiple times. So lets say that I saved all those `someChars`, one by one, into an array called `someChars`.

Would the CRC resulting from all of these chars be called via `crc16(someChars, sizeof(someChars)/sizeOf(someChars[0]))`..?

Also, would I have to use `uint8_t` type for my array?

I have no examples to go by, so I'm asking on here to make sure this is 100% right.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the `for` loop: the assignment to `data` is likely a separated line that got mangled.

Comment: It’s somewhat crazy that a code published in 2007 in Dr Dobbs uses this ancient style of C function definitions.

Answer (score 3):

There are many alternative algorithms to compute this CRC: some use lookup tables, some use bit operations, some flip some bits, some flip some other bits...

The `CRCname.put(int byte)` function you mention most likely is an update to the CRC being calculated. That is, it computes a single iteration of your inner `do/while` loop, using the passed byte (actually a `unsigned char` instead of an `int`) as the value for your `data` local variable.

In the unknown `CRCname` type there is probably a member variable that stores your `crc` variable, a constructor that sets it to its intitial value and a `int CRCname.getFinalCrcValue()` that does the final computation.

Anyway, if you do not have any example to compare your output with, it is quite unlikely you'll get it right. Too many things that can go wrong.

About the `uint8_t` type, it does not matter too much, unless your `CHAR_BITS` value is different from `8`, and if that is the case you have bigger problems!

Answer (score 0):

> Would the CRC resulting from all of these chars be called via `crc16(someChars, sizeof(someChars)/sizeOf(someChars[0]))`..?

If `someChars` is a `char` array then most likely yes (once you fix the code, `sizeOf` → `sizeof`). Note that you don’t need to divide by `sizeof(someChars[0])` since the size of a `char` in C is defined to be 1.

> Also, would I have to use `uint8_t` type for my array?

The function you posted doesn’t, so it makes no sense to pass a `uint8_t` buffer to it. That said, it would definitely be better to use an array of `uint8_t` for raw bytes, and to modify the function accordingly.

Comment: It's horrible practice to use `char` for storing raw data instead of `uint8_t`, so this answer is misleading. It happens to work in this specific example because they didn't use bit shifts directly on the data, but converted to `unsigned int`. But that doesn't make it good practice.

Comment: @Lundin I completely agree — I was simply referring to the fact that the posted “function” doesn’t use it either. But you’re right, that function should be fixed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> byte is an integer value used to update the current CRC. Only the lowest 8 bits of the parameter are used.

CRC doesn't work like that. Function like the one you posted expect to be given a full data package. There's two options of how to use such a function:

- Either the package contains only data in which case the function will calculate the FCS (frame check sequence) that should be stored in the end of the package.
- Or the package contains data + FCS, in which case you can call the very same function and get a boolean value 0 if successful, or non-zero in case of errors.

Calling the function "to update the current CRC" doesn't make any sense, because the function doesn't retain the previous FCS but starts at blank data, all ones = 0xFFFF, as required by CRC16-CCITT. If you wish to continuously update the FCS, you would have to save it then pass it to the function with each call.

In addition, the algorithm itself got a bug, `char` should not be used for raw data since it might be signed. Indeed you should be using `uint8_t` instead.

For some reason this code is written in obsolete K&R style. Given the low quality of this code... be wary of lots of rotten and incorrect implementations of CRC16-CCITT floating around on the internet. I was using a rotten one for many years which looked a lot like this one. Until I found out it wasn't actually CRC16-CCITT but non-standard.

It sounds like what you actually want is a lookup-table version, which does 16/8/4 bit look-ups, depending on how much ROM memory you can afford for it.

Comment: “CRC doesn't work like that.” — Having a stateful CRC algorithm that processes data as it comes in is actually fairly common, and an idiomatic online algorithm. The function OP posted *isn’t* an online algorithm but that’s the whole reason for OP’s confusion.